# How to inject a dependency in a library without using service location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Let's say a dev has created a library that exposes a class *ScheduledAction*

All this class does is execute a method at a specified interval.

So you would use this way:

```
var scheduledAction = new ScheduledAction(methodToCall, 10000);
scheduledAction.Start();
```

Every 10 seconds, the *methodToCall* is executed.

Now let's say dev of the library decided that ScheduledAction will catch and log exceptions thrown by *methodToCall*.

To do this it needs a logger. As this is a library, the dev doesn't want to force the use of any particular logging library and or implementation. This should be controlled and configured by the application consuming the library.

This is a very simple example to illustrate the point.

While researching on this, I noticed a common approach is to expose some sort of contract for logging (via an interface) and the consuming application has to supply an implementation, which is "injected" via some sort of initialization method that the library exposes.

However logging may not be the only dependency a library needs from a consuming application.

I'm struggling to find concrete examples/best practices for such situations, in particular when building an application that uses an IoC container, like an Asp.NET Core Web App.

All the services are added to the container at startup. I would then need to "initialize" the above mentioned library passing in implementations of the required services, requesting them explicitly, which is pretty much using the container like a service locator and more importantly the instances passed to the library cannot be swapped later (I'm thinking of cases where the IoC container creates object based on options/configuration which may change even at run-time).

Comment: Asking for opinions is off-topic on SO. Even without that explicit request the question is still not well defined - there are plenty ways to construct objects in .Net and Java (including 2 different languages/platforms does not make question more specific either)...

Comment: I understand. But unless very specific, plenty of questions on SO ultimately ask for an opinion on how to solve a particular problem, and while some are closed for this reason, many are not, which leaves me a bit confused. Anyways will try to ask better next  time around.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available:

- Expose an ILogger interface on the same lib assembly/package, and a Logger class. Have the Logger class expose a static method to set the internal logger instance to some class that implements it.
- Instead of setting up an implementation of ILogger, one could just assign an Action to be executed by the static Logger class.

The important is to have this behavior exposed through an interface, so the ScheduleAction class can be easily tested.

Then, on the ScheduleAction class, just check if the Logger has the actual logger set, and call it when an exception occurs.